# Как создать foreign key между двумя таблицами с типом XMLTYPE?

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, oracle, plsql

В БД созданы две таблицы типа `XMLTYPE` на основе XML схем.

1. регистрация XML схем:

   ```
   begin
    dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(
   'tab1_schema.xsd',
   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xs:element name="man">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="man_id" type="xs:int" />
           <xs:element name="man_name" type="xs:string" />
           <xs:element name="man_date" type="xs:date" />  
           <xs:element name="cars">
             <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="car">
                   <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element name="car_id" type="xs:int" />
                     </xs:sequence>
                   </xs:complexType>
                 </xs:element>
               </xs:sequence>
             </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>',
   true,
   true,
   false,
   false);

   dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(
   'tab2_schema.xsd',
   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xs:element name="car">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="car_id" type="xs:int" />
           <xs:element name="car_name" type="xs:string" />
           <xs:element name="car_date" type="xs:date" />        
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>',
   true,
   true,
   false,
   false);

   end;
   /
   ```
2. создание таблиц на основе XML схем:

   ```
   create table tab1 of xmltype xmlschema "tab1_schema.xsd" element "man";
   create table tab2 of xmltype xmlschema "tab2_schema.xsd" element "car";
   ```
3. создание ключей:

   ```
   alter table tab1 add constraint tab1_pk primary key (xmldata."man_id");
   alter table tab2 add constraint tab2_pk primary key (xmldata."car_id");
   ```

Как создать внешний ключ для таблицы `tab1` (элемент `/cars/car/car_id`) на таблицу `tab2` (элемент `/car_id`)?

Что-то такое нужно:

```
alter table tab1 add constraint tab1_fk
    foreign key (xmldata."/cars/car/car_id") 
    references tab2(xmldata."car_id");
```

PS версия Oracle 10gR2

Answer (score 2):

Для приведённых XML схем - никак. Это потому, что для элемента с атрибутом `maxOccurs>1`:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="car">
```

при объектно-реляционном способе хранения будет неявно создана колонка с типом данных `VARRAY`. Как следует из подглавы [Restrictions on Foreign Key Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE), создать ограничение с внешним ключом для неё не допускается:

> None of the columns in the foreign key can be of LOB, LONG, LONG RAW, **VARRAY**, NESTED TABLE, BFILE, REF, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, or user-defined type.

Что предлагaет документация ([см. подгл. Enforcing Referential Integrity Using SQL Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/how-to-use-XML-DB.html#GUID-B08A78A0-351B-431E-8F81-E02FFF0357D1)) в случае, если создать SQL ограничение невозможно:

> You can use SQL constraints **and database triggers** to ensure data-integrity properties such as uniqueness and foreign-key relations.

Создадим триггер:

```sql
create or replace trigger validateTab1Trig 
before insert or update on tab1 for each row
begin
    for r in (
        select x1."carId" 
        from xmlTable ('/man/cars/car' 
        passing :new.object_value columns "carId" integer path 'car_id') x1
        where not exists (
            select 1
            from tab2 cross join xmlTable ('/car' 
            passing tab2.object_value columns "carId" integer path 'car_id') x2
            where x2."carId" = x1."carId")
        ) loop
        raise_application_error (-20000,'car Id='||r."carId"||' does not exist (parent key not found)');     
    end loop;
end;
/
```

И попытка записи с несуществующим `car_id` приведёт к ошибке:

```sql
insert into tab1 values (
    xmlType('<man>
            <man_id>1</man_id>
            <man_name>name 1</man_name>
            <man_date>2020-03-23</man_date>
            <cars>
                <car>
                    <car_id>1</car_id> 
                </car>
                <car>
                    <car_id>2</car_id> 
                </car>
            </cars>
        </man>'));

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: car Id=1 does not exist (parent key not found)
ORA-06512: at "DB.VALIDATETAB1TRIG", line 12
```

---

PS при выборе способа хранения возьмите на заметку, что неструктурированное хранение XML документов как `CLOB` [больше не рекомендуется](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/choice-of-XMLType-storage-and-indexing.html#GUID-60132193-FCBB-4A7F-AA11-53CB660F67AF):

> **Note**: Starting with Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1), the unstructured (CLOB) storage model for XMLType is deprecated. Use binary XML storage instead.

Answer (score 1):

никак, вообще вся эта мода пихать в XMLTYPE очень плохая практика, чем вам не угодил клоб???. а вообще сделать еще одно поле, куда записывать рядом ИД ваш. либо по дефалту sys_guid и будет вам уникальный ИД

Comment: Хранение в CLOB исключает xmltype store object relational (структурное хранение xml-документа).

Comment: Вообще в идеале, что касается хмл в оракле, лучше сделать так, парсить его в таблицу,а при отправке куда-то собирать хмл, это будет намного удобнее. что касается CLOB всегда с ним работаю и никаких проблем не возникало. делайте массу проверок перед тем как его туда записать что бы валидный он был.